# Third gender or intersex

Tags: word-request, terminology

What is the term used for a baby born with biological conditions that do not fit the typical definitions for male or female bodies? What is used in the UK and USA?

> Is the term 'intersex' acceptable?

Can we say, 'The baby was born intersex'?

Or the term 'third gender' is acceptable?

My question is about the one who is naturally born in such state as mentioned here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersex#The_term_%22intersex%2

Comment: Political / sociological arguments about gender classifications aren't going to be resolved by reference to traditional language definitions. This question is inherently Primarily Opinion-Based

Answer (score 2):

The technical term is indeed intersex as you suggest. It refers to facts about biological aspects of the person. Gender is usually used in the technical literature to refer to roles which people take on. In some cultures there are well-defined third (and more) gender roles which are filled by people whose biology is typical of one or other sex. Note however that in lay vocabulary sex and gender are often used interchangeably.